# recordMyDesktop rendering is bad

Tags: recordmydesktop

I have used recordMyDesktop for a while an it worked very good, but now it have begin to draw lines through the desktop on the rendered video. I don't know how that happened, but it would be good to still be using recordMyDesktop. I hope you guys have an answer to this. It would be good. But if you haven't an answer I maybe have to change desktop recorded. Then you can give me some advice of which program I should use then. Thanks in advice :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This one](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/simplescreenrecorder-powerful-screen.html) is pure awesome :D I believe it is the best one there is